# how to connect Brave browser with Netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, brave

I would like to use the "Brave" browser to view my html projects but netbeans only let me link with Chrome and the Microsoft browsers. I have downloaded the connector extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuring a NetBeans web application to run in ***Brave*** is a three step process:

**Step 1 of 3:**

Locate the full path to `brave.exe` for your ***Brave*** installation.

- On my Windows 10 machine it is `C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Brave\Brave.exe`, but obviously your path will be different.

**Step 2 of 3:**

Add Brave to the list of browsers that NetBeans supports:

- In NetBeans select **Tools > Options > General > Web Browser > Edit...** to open the **Web Browsers Manager** window.
- Click the **Add..** button to add an entry in the **Web Browsers** list:

  - In the **Name** field enter ***Brave***.
  - In the **Process** field enter the full path to **Brave.exe** identified in step 1 above.
  - Enter any [arguments for Brave](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/393) in the **Arguments** text box.

    [image: addBrowser1]

**Step 3 of 3:** 
Configure your web project to use Brave by default:

- Select **Properties > Run** from the context menu of the web application you want to run.
- Select the new entry ***Brave*** from the **Browser** drop list:

  [image: addBrowser2]

After doing that your web application will open in ***Brave*** when run from NetBeans. Obviously you only need to follow step 3 for other web applications to run in ***Brave*** as well.